# "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found" not able to resolve on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04, x509certificate

- I'm trying to access a remote server from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
- I have mapped the remote server IP to "localhost:60000".
- I'm able to access the server via web browser as well as CURL commands. I'm getting the response as expected.
- Unfortunately, I'm not able to establish a connection from the Java code, which results in below exception,

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost
>   found

I did find a solution in the links below:

- For Ubuntu 14.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04
- For Ubuntu 16.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

The issue is resolved on Ubuntu 14.04 machine but not on 16.04 machine.
Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: plz provide your CURL commands ??

Comment: "curl -k -u username:password https://localhost:60000/getmap"

Comment: r u adding the your crt to keytool

Comment: yes, I have used the command,

_keytool -import -file /etc/ssl/certs/localhostself.crt -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias localselfcert_

Comment: instead of `localselfcert` as alias name try with `localhost`

Comment: I just tried with alias name as _localhost_ , still the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties;




TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {}
}};

private Client getSSLClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, this.certs, null);
    config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, ctx));
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    return client;
}
```